# Try/Catch to NOT do something on error

Tags: powershell

I have a script that consists of three lines:

```
Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $Computer -Force -RandomDelayInMinutes 0
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
Close-UserSession -Computer $Computer -Force -Reboot
```

(`Close-UserSession` is a function that ultimately just invokes Win32ShutdownTracker on the remote computer to reboot it.)

On occasion, `Invoke-GPUpdate` can't reach the target computer, and throws an error. If it does throw an error, I do *not* want to execute the `Start-Sleep` or `Close-UserSession`.

Essentially, what I need could almost be described as "Try/Anti-catch". It's got to be possible; the question is ... how do I do this?

(Note: I don't insist on using Try/Catch; it's just the best way to illustrate my need.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try,

```
try
{
Invoke-GPUpdate -Computer $Computer -Force -RandomDelayInMinutes 0
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
Close-UserSession -Computer $Computer -Force -Reboot
}
catch 
{
    Write-Output "Remote Computer: $Computer Could not be reached!"
}
```

Comment: Y'know, I read `about_Try_Catch_Finally` several times, and I didn't get the sense that this would work - so I pretty much dismissed T/C/F. Looking at it again, I see that yes, that's the way it's supposed to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You put the full script in the `try`, and nothing in the `catch`; this way, if an error occurs w/ the first line, it will abandon the other 2 and go to the `catch`.